# Calling Codeigniter Model Methods by Variable

Tags: php, methods

I'm trying to call the method of a loaded model by a variable name instead of a hard coded method name.  This will give me a ton of abstraction in my controller without using a bunch of if-then statements.

Here's the Model

```
class Reports_model extends CI_Model {

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->load->database();
  }

  public function backlog()
  {
    //Do stuff
  }
```

What I want is to be able to call the backlog function by a variable name.  Here's the controller:

```
class Reports extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function get_reports($report_name)
  {
    $this->load->model('reports_model');
    $report_name = 'backlog';
    $data['data'] = $this->reports_model->$report_name();
  }
```

From what I can tell (and I'm probably missing something stupid), my code is exactly like Example #2 on http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php, but I'm getting this error at the line of the function call:

Undefined property: Reports::$reports_model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use autoloader for this model. Autoloader file is in appilication/config/ folder. You must you model in

```
$autoload['model'] = array('Reports_model');
```

Or you can use

```
class Reports extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Reports_model');

  }

  public function get_reports($report_name)
  {
    $report_name = 'backlog';
    $data['data'] = $this->Reports_model->backlog();
  }
}
```

You must be write upper first character of the model like this : `$this->Reports_model->backlog()`
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy

Comment: The second answer would certainly work, but I'm hoping to not have a method in the controller for every model method, so I'm hoping to display have one method in the Controller to call a method by the same name in the Model without having to specify (if that makes sense).  It's going to make it much more flexible later to add things without changing the code.

Comment: ok you can use codeigniter router for this problem. (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) Create a rooter and all request call same controller method. And in this method, you can use `call_user_func` default php function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php#example-4726

Comment: Ok, the capital R in both places did work, which is bizarre because I literally have 100 other of these model loads/method calls going on where I abused the casing and those work.

Answer (score 1):

You did not load the reports model, change your constructor in the controller:

```
 public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load>model('Reports_model');
  }
```

Comment: I did actually, I just cut that part out when I was trying to clean the code up for display.  I'll edit the question to show that.

Comment: change it to upper case: 'Reports_model' not 'reports_model', also, it is better to load it in the constructor, unless this is the only function you use it

Comment: No luck with the upper case 'R', although I've always used lower case for these (this app already has about 30 parts to it) and it's gone fine.  Good point on loading it in the construction, although if I get this variable method going this will be the only method that uses the reports model.

Comment: Ok, the capital R in both places did work, which is bizarre because I literally have 100 other of these model loads/method calls going on where I abused the casing and those work.